# RPI Issue with entry boxes tkinter?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, raspberry-pi

> Struggling to get a simple form to work in a tkinter instance. Is
> there a known issue with not being able to click on tk.Entry boxes?
> I'll take the key parts of the code out to see if anyone can spot
> something i'm doing wrong?

```
class CreateWindow():
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.root.overrideredirect(True)
        ***Then I do a whole load of importing images, setting background and other stuff ***
        self.messageText = tk.StringVar()
        self.MessageBox = tk.Entry(self.root, textvariable = self.messageText)
        self.MessageBox.place(x=100, y=100)
        self.root.mainloop()
```

This code is then called from if main = name

Does anyone see anything I'm doing wrong??

Comment: I never seen tk.root() before. For me it must be tk.Tk()

Comment: And you never placed the widget on your application. Somewhere you need to do self.Messagebox.pack() or another layoutmanager.

Comment: You may want to take a look at this before you follow and go ahead with your code.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17466561/best-way-to-structure-a-tkinter-application

Comment: the mainloop() should be the last bit of code, except you want to run code after you close your window. Because the mainloop just reads the cod till it is called, everything beyond will not included.

Comment: Also set self to messageText, espacally with vars its recommanded to debugg.

Comment: My apologies. I typed my code out really badly.

Comment: `overrideredirect` on some systems inhibits the program from taking focus. Do you still see the problem if you remove the line that sets that option to True?

Comment: @TheOuz Are you useing focus_force() somewhere ?

Comment: @BryanOakley I removed overrideredirect and am no longer experiencing the problem. Is there any way to work around this? I am producing a GUI that has many different functions. This specific slide needs to take user input to communicate with a server. However without the overrideredirect it no longer follows the design scheme of the rest of the windows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why I cannot click on the entry box is that root.overrideredirect(True) prevents the entry box from getting focus. I have listed a new question [RPI Tkinter Window, I want to use a command like overrideredirect and maintain entry box functionality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62694656/rpi-tkinter-window-i-want-to-use-a-command-like-overrideredirect-and-maintain-e) to focus on how to work around this.