# RPI Tkinter Window, I want to use a command like overrideredirect and maintain entry box functionality

Tags: python, forms, tkinter, raspberry-pi

When using `overrideredirect` or something like `root.wm_attributes('-type', 'splash')` my entry box cannot get focus on user's click.

I am developing a GUI which I want to maintain the style of previous windows and not have this window stand out with the window header. How do I get rid of the RPI window bar but maintain entry box functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using the splash window type (Linux only), you can make the entry get the keyboard focus by using `focus_force()`, e.g. binding it to the left click.

```
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()
root.wm_attributes('-type', 'splash')
e = tk.Entry(root)
e.pack()
# force focus on left click:
root.bind('<1>', lambda ev: ev.widget.focus_force())
root.mainloop()
```